# Изменить span на input и обратно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько товаров в таблице с их количеством. Если пользователь хочет изменить количество, нажимает на значение ,  исчезает и появляется . Как сделать чтобы при исчезновении фокуса от input, input исчезал и появлялся span, но при этом введенное значение сохранялось

```js
function edit_qty(id_num) {
    $("#"+id_num).prop("type", "number").focus().select();
    $("#id_"+id_num).prop("class", "no_display");
}
```

```css
.no_display{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<td class='center pointer h43' onclick="edit_qty('$uniq')">
  <input type='hidden' name='prod_qty_{$uniq}' value='{$uniq_arr[$uniq]}' id='$uniq'>
  <span id='id_{$uniq}'>{$uniq_arr[$uniq]}</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Почему не развернуть всё в input и избавится от span?

Comment: Изначально хотел обойтись только с input, добавляя и убирая disabled, но я не силен в js, не осилил. Какой у вас вариант реализации без span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать чтобы при исчезновении фокуса от input, input исчезал и появлялся span, но при этом введенное значение сохранялось

Предложу такой вариант решения...

```js
$('table td').on('click', test)
$('table input').on('blur', test)
//
function test(e) {
  const o = e.target.closest('td')
  if (!o) return
  const oi = o.querySelector('input')
  const os = o.querySelector('span')
  if (oi.type === 'hidden') {
    oi.type = 'text'
    oi.value = os.textContent
    oi.select()
    return
  }
  os.textContent = oi.value
  oi.type = 'hidden'
}
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
td [type='text'] + span {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' />
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' />
      <span>2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' />
      <span>3</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' />
      <span></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' />
      <span></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' />
      <span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо)

Comment: как повесить эти функции js на ссылку, например: <a href='#' onclick="test()">Изменить</a>

Comment: @ШерзодЖумабаев, все навешивается аналогично. Главное правильно указать селектор, который будет определять ту ссылку.

Comment: Никак не смог навешать на <a>. Javascript'у не обучался((
Еще один момент: изменил в вашем коде тип поля с text на number, так как туда только цифровые значения должны вводить, но в таком случае span не исчезает, встает рядом с input

Comment: Добавил pattern для цифр в input type='hidden', но не помогло

Comment: @ШерзодЖумабаев, имеет смысл тебе создать еще один вопрос с неким конкретным примером